# Why does my css animation keep restarting when I add new elements with animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So when I click a button i append some html to the dom which gets animated, when I press the button again more html gets appended to the dom and gets animated.. My issue is that every element that i've appended always gets animated when i press the button. I want it to only get animated once, is this possible without using javascript to add and remove classes ?

```
.additional-text{
    animation:fadein 4s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
```

the Div that gets appended has the additional-text class.

https://jsfiddle.net/t7ykv86r/

Comment: I think it happens because the whole div is rewritten. When you append something, Javascript doesn't only "put" the new element below it. It rewrites it completely in the DOM, making think the browser that is a "new" element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because you're using `innerHTML` to update the DOM which means you convert an entire section of the DOM to string, add another DOM string to it, then convert back and render, which rerenders that entire section.

You should create and append nodes instead.

```
function addMoreText(){
  var text = document.createElement('div')
  text.classList.add('additional-text');
  text.innerHTML = '<p>Even More of my text</p>';
  var textEle = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0];
  textEle.appendChild(text)
}
```

[See Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/t7ykv86r/1/)

Comment: using this instead "textEle.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', text);" THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround you may try:

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
let count = 0;
button.addEventListener("click", addMoreText);

function addMoreText(){
  count += 1
  var text = "<div class=`${count > 1 ? null : 'additional-text'}`><p>More of my text</p><p>Even More of my text</p></div>"
  var textEle = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0];
  textEle.innerHTML += text;
}
```